# CUDA problem Error: Invalid value in cuMemcpy2DUnaligned(&param)

Tags: rendering

does anybody know what this error mean:

*Error: Invalid value in cuMemcpy2DUnaligned(&param) (device_cuda_impl.cpp:1248)Invalid value in cuMemcpy2DUnaligned(&param) (device_cuda_impl.cpp:1248)*

I need help...I tried everything but I cannot render with my two Graphic card GTX 970. On the other hand, CPU rendering works fine...

Thanks!

Comment: Are all your drivers up to date?

Comment: Yup...they are :(

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to your problem, but an assertion that I too have come across this phenomenon and a workaround:

I had this with a system of mine that has 2x Quadro K4000 GPUs. The culprit was a scene that does not fit into the GPU memory. As per a [patch in Blender 2.80](https://developer.blender.org/T48651), there was an option added that would let Blender render such scenes by swapping memory in and out as needed. This works well on single GPU systems, but dual GPU systems have an issue with that. I'm not sure why. Up until recently (2.83 or so), the scene would render a few frames and then stop. With 2.92, it refuses to render on first attempt, throwing the above error.

My workaround was to disable any one of the GPUs, resulting in a render without the error. One of my GPUs (probably the one connected to my monitor) was rendering way slower than the other one. It's worth doing a test and using the faster of the two. While it's not an ideal solution, it might at least get your scene rendered.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Jay for your answer.