# Can't render scene in 3.4 or 3.5, receiving different errors

Tags: error

I have a scene which renders very quickly in the Viewport with Viewport Shading and Cycles, but when I try to use Render Image, it doesn't work. I've received the following errors on different attempts:

"Invalid value in cuMemcpy2DUnaligned(&param)"

"Failed to create CUDA context (Illegal address)"

"System is out of GPU memory"

The scene is using 8/24 GB of VRAM according to Blender. I'm using a GTX 3090 and GTX 3090TI, Ryzen 5900, and 128GB. I have tried the scene in Blender 3.4 and 3.5. I've upgraded to the latest Nvidia drivers as of today.

I have tried adding a new scene to the project and rendering as suggested in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282251/failed-to-create-cuda-context-illegal-address) work around. I've also tried disabling one of my 2 GPUs, as suggested in [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211696/cuda-problem-error-invalid-value-in-cumemcpy2dunalignedparam). And last I've tried to add a bounding box to the scene, as suggested [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245821/how-to-fix-this-error-illegal-address-in-cuda-queue-copy-from-device-integrato).

I was able to successfully render a frame once by disabling one GPU, but it took 4 minutes, compared to 10 seconds that Viewport Shading takes. It also crashed when I tried a second render.

I was also able to render a frame by rendering a 1-frame animation rather than still image. But Blender was unable to render another frame and gave me the error "System is out of GPU memory"

UPDATE: I've been able to successfully render by copying all elements of my project into a new one. I'd love to know what is actually causing the errors, but is copy/pasting into a new scene a typical workaround for Blender errors?